# C Linked lists with global variables

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I'm new to C and I'm struggling to get a linked list working I'm having to use global variables because I can't change the parameters of the function that is being called. I declare the struct and two global pointers to keep track of the root address and last address like this.

```
struct node {
  char* pointer;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node** rootNode;
struct node** lastNode;
```

Then inside the function I malloc a new struct and try to setup the first node in the list. To try and save the location of this node I think I'm assigning the global pointer lastNode to the pointer of root.

```
struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
...
root->pointer=ptr;
root->next = 0;
    rootNode = &root;
lastNode = &root;
```

Then I try to add aditional nodes by mallocing another node and then linking the previous node using the address stored in my lastNode pointer.

```
struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

newNode->pointer=ptr ;
(*lastNode)->next = newNode;
newNode->next = 0;
lastNode = &newNode;
```

However this doesn't really seem to work. When I run the following the program matches the first two items in the list but then returns null for all nodes after that. I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and any help would really be appreciated :)

```
struct node* test;
test = (*rootNode);
enter code here
while (test) {
       if (test->pointer == ptr) {
       printf("MATCH!!");
       notFound = 0;
       break;
       }
    else {
    test = test->next;
    }
}
```

*EDIT* A couple of people have asked me to supply some more code. This is the function in which I would like to create the linked list. It's called multiple times while my program is running and I'm trying to add a new node to my linked list every time it gets called. I've also included the global variables at the top.

```
struct node** rootNode;
struct node** lastNode;
int firstRun = 1;

struct node {
char* pointer;
struct node *next;
};

void malloc(size_t sz) {

size_t maxSize = (size_t)-1;  
char * payloadPtr = NULL;

if (sz > maxSize - sizeof(struct node)+sizeof(int)) {
return ptr;
  }

  if (firstRun) {

struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)+sz);

if (ptr == NULL) {
    return ptr;
    }
memcpy(ptr, &sz, sizeof(int));
payloadPtr = ptr+1;
root->pointer=payloadPtr; 
root->next = 0;
rootNode = &root;
lastNode = &root;
firstRun = 0;

  }
  else { 
struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)+sz);

if (ptr == NULL) {
  return ptr;
}
memcpy(ptr, &sz, sizeof(int));
payloadPtr =ptr+1;
newNode->pointer= payloadPtr; 
(*lastNode)->next = newNode;
newNode->next = 0;
lastNode = &newNode;                
}

return payloadPtr;
}
```

Comment: why are you not using double pointer instead of single pointer?

Comment: `newNode->pointer=ptr ;`  What is `ptr` ?

Comment: @Tonmoy - Perhaps you missed the first 5 words of the post. I'll repeat them for your benefit. "Hi I'm new to C"

Comment: `struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` why this line is repeated? and did you malloc for every new node?

Comment: @enhzflep  yes.I noticed that. That's why i was suggesting you to use single pointer instead of double pointer...both does the same thing.but handling double pointer is more complicated than single pointer.

Comment: I thought if I used single pointers it wouldn't work. Maybe that's just when they are being passed in functions??

Comment: Sorry about that. In my actuall code struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); isn't repeated. I've edited the question to fix.

Comment: In `struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, what is the lifetime of `root`? If this is a declaration inside a function, the pointer `root` that is declared here has automatic storage duration; it exists only as long as the function is executing. In that case, a global variable pointing to `root` is useless after the function exits; the pointer `root` no longer exists after the function exits.

Comment: Right I see. I thought that if I malloced something it would remain in  memory until called free or the program finished?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I looked at answering this, but decided it was going to be difficult because the necessary information is missing. Please research how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). It would help a lot to see the interfaces you're using. You are not forced by C to use global variables. You might well pass in a 'pointer to pointer' to the root node, or you might return the new root node each time you call the function (both techniques work), but since we can't see all your code, it is hard to know.

Comment: Agreed, it's pointless without seeing working code, anything could be happening.

Comment: @Tonmoy - Well actually, the suggestion was implied. Regardless of your intention, what you actually did was ask why Ian chose one alternative over another. I merely quoted the glaringly obvious answer. Perhaps you would benefit from revising your question asking, er I mean suggestion-making skills?

Answer (score 0):

There's a little clarification about changing the parameters into a function. In C you can only pass by pointers on function calls so if you want to modify the value of a struct node - you pass it like struct node * in the function. Similarly if you want to change the value of a struct node * in the function (as in allocate it or delete it) you may want to pass it like struct node **.

Your function prototype will probably have to look like this:

`void addNode(struct node** root, char* value)`

But you can also make that root node a local and also just a struct node * instead of struct node **. And then simply call it like:

`addNode(&root, value);`